# time complexity heapsort alogrithm

Tags: time-complexity, heapsort

The heapsort time complexity is nlog(n) in all cases.

But I do not understand why because we must call n times the heapify algorithm ont the child binary trees with "i" which are already ilog(i) complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The heapify operation takes `O(lg(n))` time. When you swap the max/min node with another one from the bottom of your heap, you will have to push that node back to the bottom. Because there are `n` elements and the height of the heap is equal `lg(n)`, you will do `lg(n)` swaps as your node traverses the heap down. If you repeat this `n` times, the time will be `O(nlg(n))`.

In the worst case (input sorted, but in reverse order) both building heap and sorting will be `O(nlg(n))`. In the best case (sorted input) building will be `O(n)` and sorting will be `O(nlg(n))` (`O(n)` if input consists of equal values). In average case building will be in between best and worst case, sorting will be `O(nlg(n))`.

Comment: I thought a binary tree was such that each parent has at most 2 children.

Comment: @RonanTarikDrevon Sorry, I misread your question. I thought you meant binary search trees. In binary trees each key has at most 2 children and that's the only property of binary trees.